# ASP.NET core 1.0 IIS 502.5 Error

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I have a asp.net core website that runs fine on IIS express on my local PC, runs fine on a Development server IIS (2012R2) and also fine on a production server IIS (2012R2) but when I put it on the DMZ production server (2008R2) I get the following error (i am running the console application from the web app folder to see the error) -

[image]

as it says the issue happens in program.cs at line 21 which is -

[image: code to run web app]

As you can see this is the normal default code for starting the application.

When I try to view the webpage it give me a 502.5 error

[image]

Has anyone had the same issue? I have spent a while Googleing but nothing has helped so far :/

Answer (score 0):

So after working out the differences between the servers it turns out that our infrastructure team have not updated the DMZ server to have latest .net framework. after updating all worked....

wish MS would give a little better error message.... o well all works now.